# How to prevent going back to login form after successful login in Spring MVC if browser back button being pressed?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, back-button

Controller class:

```
package com.ym.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class CustomerController {

@RequestMapping(value="/home")
public String goHome(){
    return "home";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/first")
public String first(HttpSession session){
    if(session.getAttribute("visited") != null){
        return "home";
    }
    else{
        return "form";
    }
}

@RequestMapping(value="/second", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String second(HttpSession session){
    session.setAttribute("visited", true);
    return "home";
}
}
```

form.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <style type="text/css">@import url("<c:url value="/css/main.css"/>");
</style>

    <title>Login Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form:form action="second" method="post">

    <p>
        <input id="reset" type="reset" tabindex="4">
        <input id="submit" type="submit" tabindex="5">
    </p>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="<c:url value="/first"/>">Go to form page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">  

   <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/springmvc-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>    
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

springmvc-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.ym.controller"/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.ym.service"/>

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/"/>


<bean id="viewResolver" 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

So the flow is, first we go to "/home". In home.jsp, there is a link to the "/first" request-handling method, which will check the "visited" attribute of session, if it is not null it will return form.jsp, in which we set the "visited" attribute of session to true, otherwise go back to home.jsp.
The problem is, even after the session attribute "visited" has been set to true, I can still go back to form.jsp by clicking the back button in the browser, but if I type in URL bar http://localhost:9001/ExperimentProject1/first, I'll be redirected to the home.jsp, because indeed "visited" attribute has been set to true. Can someone explain me what is happening here? Why clicking the back button has different effect with typing manually the URI?
This is just an analogy for login mechanism.

Comment: Change the login page so it doesn't do a normal `<form>` POST, but instead does it with ajax, and on success replaces the current page with the intended target page.

Answer (score 0):

Use "redirect:home" instead of "home". This is probably the most well known approach.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. I still land in form.jsp if I hit the back button from home.jsp.

Comment: in both first() and second() methods?